# Create a dynamic CollapsiblePanel using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Can somebody provide me a sample on creating a dynamic CollapsiblePanel using ASP.NET C#.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Take a look at Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/. It's free and provides a lot of responsive Web-UI-Elements. It should be already in your Asp.Net Project.

Answer (score 2):

AjaxControlToolkit home (wiki) is now here: 
https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/wiki.

samples:
https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/Default.aspx